# using ' in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I am using a tooltip plugin (qTip 2.0) and trying to specify content for the tooltip.

I get an error `unterminated string literal`

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('.tool').qtip({
content: 'Don\'t want...', 
position: {
  my: 'bottom left', 
  at: 'top left', 
  target: $j('.tool') 
  },
  style: {
  classes: 
  'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded ui-tooltip-tipsy'
}
});
</script>
```

In the Content you will see the word `Don't` I understand that JS will see the `'` as an end to the `content` how do I get it to read Don't properly?

I have tried `Don\'t` and that did not work. I have tried changing `'` to `"` and that did not work.

I know there is a way around this I cannot remember though! Help!

Comment: `Don\'t` should have worked. What does the syntax error say specifically?

Comment: `var xyz = 'Don\'t want...';` should actually be working...

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I get an error `unterminated string literal`

Comment: Just to be sure, if you change it to 'Do not...', i.e., remove the apostrophe, does the error go away?

Comment: I got it working, not sure what the actual error was but I changed some of the code with " and now it works, go figure

Comment: Sometimes what you think is a single quote might not actually be a single quote (it could be a backquote) and it's next to impossible to see that difference, but the JS interpreter sees it.  This is notoriously common when code is edited in a word processor that likes to get fancy with backquotes.

Comment: That could of been the issue not sure but I use DW to edit and create code =>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting double quotes around the content with the single quote, should fix it.

```
...
content: "Don't want...",
...
```

Does this help?

Comment: I still get the error this is why I am so confused as I tried `"`

Comment: I made a few changed and used " and it works now...not sure what the issue was but oh well it works =>

Answer (score 3):

Use the escape character. Example:

```
var content = 'It\'s the escape character you want.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why the escape character isn't working. But you could also try the HTML equivalent for the \ symbol

```
 &#92;
```